# Why am I getting stackoverflow error with ZIO Ref

Tags: scala, zio

Below is a memoized version of Fibonacci function implemented in ZIO.

If the highlighted line `_ <- memo.get` is commented out the function fib results in a Stackoverflow error. If it is un-commented the code works as expected.

Why does this `get` call on the memo Ref is needed to make this function work? and why without it we are running into a stackoverflow error?

```
object Main extends ZIOAppDefault {

  private def compute(num: Int, memo: Ref[Map[Int, Int]]): UIO[Int] = for {
    _ <- memo.get // commenting this line will result in Stackoverflow Error
    a1 <- fib(num - 1, memo)
    a2 <- fib(num - 2, memo)
  } yield a1 + a2

  private def fib(num: Int, memo: Ref[Map[Int, Int]]): UIO[Int] = {
    if(num <= 1)
      ZIO.succeed(1)
    else
      for {
        map  <- memo.get
        res <- map.get(num).map(x => ZIO.succeed(x)).getOrElse(compute(num, memo))
      } yield res
  }

  private def calculate(num: Int) = for {
    map <- Ref.make[Map[Int, Int]](Map())
    res <- fib(num, map)
  } yield res

  override def run: ZIO[Any with ZIOAppArgs with Scope, Any, Any] = calculate(9).debug

}
```

Comment: Which version of ZIO are You using? Seems to be working fine for ZIO `2.0.0` with the line commented out.

Comment: Just a heads up (I know that it was not your primarily question), but you're not updating the `memo`, so your memoization is not happening

Comment: @DominikWosiński yes I am using 2.0 and did you comment out the 3'rd line ?